# Deploying project, created with Eclipse and Maven, to Tomcat

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, maven-2, m2eclipse

I'm using Eclipse 3.5, Maven 2, m2eclipse and Tomcat 6. So i create Maven project for archetype webapp. 
This is pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">  
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion> 
    <groupId>com.itransition</groupId>
    <artifactId>hello</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>hello Maven Webapp</name> 
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <!-- tools.jar dependency -->    
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>default-tools.jar</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>java.vendor</name>
                    <value>Sun Microsystems Inc.</value>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
                    <version>1.5.0</version>
                    <scope>system</scope>
                    <systemPath>${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>hello</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

So then i want to deploy my web application to Tomcat. What I need to do? Maven install don't help. But if I create war by Maven install, i can import it to eclipse and deploy it to Tomcat by "Add and remove..." in server popup.

Comment: BTW, what the hell is this default-tools.jar profile?!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This problem can be resolved by using the Tomcat plugin for Maven. Its homepage has got extensive documentation concerning the [configuration](https://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-trunk/tomcat7-maven-plugin/usage.html) of the plugin and [deployment of war files](https://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.0-beta-1/tomcat6-maven-plugin/examples/deployment-tomcat7.html).

Comment: Sorry for stupid question, but how can I get this plugin? I don't find any download page.

Comment: No problem. When you add the plugin configuration to your pom.xml file, Maven will download the plugin and its dependencies automatically.

Comment: so I add to pom.xml
<plugins>  
     <plugin>  
         <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>  
         <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>  
            <configuration>  
                 <url>http://localhost:8080/manager</url>  
            </configuration>  
      </plugin>  
        </plugins>  
Then run "mvn tomcat:deploy", and get
[INFO] Deploying war to http://localhost:8080/hello  
[INFO]
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] 
[INFO] Cannot invoke Tomcat manager

Embedded error: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://localhost:8080/manager/deploy?path=%2Fhello&war=

Comment: 403 probably means that you should add the username and password needed to access the tomcat manager application to your pom.xml file. 

The Tomcat side of the configuration is described here: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/manager-howto.html#Configuring%20Manager%20Application%20Access 

Also, see Section named 'Using Different Tomcat Manager Authentication Details' from here:

http://mojo.codehaus.org/tomcat-maven-plugin/configuration.html

Comment: When you install Tomcat directly from Eclipse (using Eclipse's "Download And Install" button), it doesn't have the Manager webapp. You need to manually download Tomcat to get the Manager.

Answer (score 5):

It can be done in 2 ways.

1. Refer below URL

   http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-create-a-web-application-project-with-maven/
2. Create maven Project with eclipse and locate the project folder from command prompt (or) Terminal
3. mvn eclipse:eclipse -Dwtpversion=2.0  [ in project folder ]

[image: From Terminal locate your webproject]

4. Refersh Eclipse project.
5. Now you can Add and Remove Deployment.

[image: Eclipse ScreenPrint]

Answer (score 4):

Found out that the tomcat manager url (i am using Tomcat 6.0) is `http://localhost:8080/manager/html`, while the default used by the mvn tomcat plugin stops at manager in the URL. Add the url specified to your pom.xml as a configuration parameter - (see this url for more details http://mojo.codehaus.org/tomcat-maven-plugin/configuration.html) and voilà it works...

With Tomcat7, I found I needed to set up the URL as `http://localhost:8080/manager/html` **and** use a username with a manager-gui role. However, using a username with the manager-script role, with URL `http://localhost:8080/manager/text` also works and is more appropriate. The manager-script role is the designed way to go for ant/maven scripts.

Answer (score 3):

> So then i want to deploy my web application to Tomcat. What I need to do? Maven install don't help. But if I create war by Maven install, i can import it to eclipse and deploy it to Tomcat by "Add and remove..." in server popup.

Since you are using m2eclipse, my recommendation would be to deploy your application using the WTP. Assuming you have the *Maven integration for WTP* feature installed (from [m2eclipse extras](http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/installing-m2eclipse.html)) and Tomcat configured as Server, just **right-click** on your project and select **Run > Run on Server...**

Another option would be to run your application on Jetty (yes, I know that this is not what you're asking for but this is very valid option if you don't want to use the WTP). Add the following snippet to your pom:

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    ...
    <plugins>
      ...
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.10</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

And simply run `mvn jetty:run` to start an embedded Jetty server and deploy your application on it.

The same can be achieved for Tomcat using the [Tomcat Maven Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/tomcat-maven-plugin) but unless you want to deploy to a remote Tomcat (see the [Usage](http://mojo.codehaus.org/tomcat-maven-plugin/usage.html) page), I don't see any advantage over the [Maven Jetty Plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Maven+Jetty+Plugin).

During development, I would use the first option (deploy with the WTP).

Comment: When I deploy application with WTP, I have 404 error on pages.

Comment: @fatkh You have another problem somewhere or you are doing something wrong but I guarantee that it works for the rest of us.

Answer (score 0):

If you want that your `war` file created by `maven`, should be deploy on tomcat server directly then this [tomcat deployment configuration](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-deploy-a-maven-web-application-to-tomcat.html) can help you.