# How to run this spring rest maven project in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, tomcat

i have found this web application on git hub based on spring mvc,ajax and restful web services and i have imported that project as existing maven project and ran as maven build by giving goal eclipse:eclipse and build was success too ,but i am not getting option to run on tomcat server ,my question is how do i run this project on tomcat?
here are the link to download this project
[github link](https://github.com/Fruzenshtein/MobileApp/releases/tag/v0.2)

[blog link](http://fruzenshtein.com/spring-mvc-ajax-jquery/)

Comment: [Just Check here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891859/deploying-project-created-with-eclipse-and-maven-to-tomcat) you will find your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This goal eclipse:eclipse -Dwtpversion=2.0 converts it to eclipse project 
and its running now on tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

`mvn clean install` should create a war file in the `target` folder which you can deploy to your favorite app server.
Or do you want to run Tomcat from within eclipse and deploy the app automatically?

Comment: how can i open maven command promt ,when i m opening its comming for a second and going

Comment: Basically you will have to add the Maven directory to the environment variable `PATH`. See https://maven.apache.org/install.html for details.
But you wrote that you had run `mvn eclipse:eclipse` successfully, you should be able to run `mvn clean install` in a similar way.